# Acrobat opens on wrong monitor without header visible

Tags: multiple-monitors, adobe-acrobat

I have two monitors, one in landscape and the other in portrait mode to make it easier to read and annotate full pages of PDFs. The first PDF opens in that location without a problem. Unfortunately, every time I open a new PDF, it's opened in the portrait orientation (very tall), but on the landcape-oriented monitor. It starts approximately centered on the monitor, so the top of the window is not visible. I can get it to move down by resizing the window using the right side margin, but I would prefer either (a) it opens automatically on the second monitor where other PDFs are opened or (b) it opens so that I can easily drag the window over without having to resize.

[image]

Setup details:

- Monitors: both 1920x1080
- OS: Windows 10
- Graphics Card: Radeon HD 7870
- Adobe Acrobat Pro DC

Answer (score 0):

The first problem has a workaround: In Preferences, Page Display, set Zoom to Fit Visible.

Second problem is harder - you drag the Acrobat window to the second monitor and close it without maximizing. It will then open that pdf on that monitor. But it seems to be a per-pdf setting, i.e. you have to do it for every pdf, which is pretty silly...

Comment: Ya, per-pdf settings don't work for me because I'm not opening the same ones over and over again. It's a lot of new PDFs every time.